# How does VkSubpassDependency work when srcSubpass = VK_EXTERNAL?

Tags: vulkan

I'm learning Vulkan from the tutorial: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation

```
VkSubpassDependency dependency{};
dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependency.dstSubpass = 0;

dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;

dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT
```

If srcSubpass = VK_EXTERNAL then ONLY in this case will srcStageMask mean the stages that are expected by this "implicit" subpass. For all other srcStageMask values (for example, srcStageMask = 0 and dstStageMask = 1), it would mean "wait for srcStageMask stages before executing stages dstStageMask). Did I get that right?

Answer (score 1):

The code above indicates that the first subpass (index 0) has a dependency on drawing commands that are executed outside (here srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL means before) the current render pass instance. This informs the GPU that it has a limited ability to execute drawing commands from different command buffers in parallel.

Anyway, I'm currently writing a tutorial series on learning Vulkan from scratch that covers these topics in greater detail than other available tutorials. You may find it helpful to check it out at: https://paminerva.github.io/docs/LearnVulkan/LearnVulkan

Comment: Hello, I would like to clarify: 
                                                                                                                                                  
1. I have one single render pass and one subpass.
2. VkSubpassDependency is used here so that "implicit" subpass, which converts image from initialLayout to layout in VkAttachmentReference structure, doesn't start before VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, but it doesn't match what you said.
3. I left a link to the tutorial I learned and it says a bit different.

Comment: @Dimas: On "2", there is no need. Every subpass always happens after layout transitions defined by that subpass. You don't need an explicit dependency; you already told Vulkan that there was a layout transition when you specified the starting layout and the subpass's required layout. And there is no "implicit subpass" before subpass 0.

Comment: @Dimas: "*I left a link to the tutorial I learned and it says a bit different.*" No, it doesn't. You are misinterpreting what it says. I don't like its "implicit subpass" wording, but it does explicitly say "before or after the render pass". Render pass layout happens *during* the render pass, not before or after it.

Comment: 1 - It also works if you have one render pass with a single subpass. GPUs, whenever possible, start executing commands in a command buffer (in the context of a render pass instance) even if the execution of commands in the previous command buffers is not yet complete. Therefore, you need to inform the GPU that it can start processing draw commands from the first subpass of the next command buffer and execute shaders up to a specific stage.

Comment: 2 - There's no implicit subpass. The current subpass depends on the subpass in the previous render pass instance (refer to point 1)..

Comment: @PAM, I realized that the draw commands run before dstStageMask and wait for the srcStageMask stage of the pipeline. But I don't understand how this restricts the transition layout, it can still execute without restriction. I think it waits for srcStageMask before executing, but you wrote that dstStageMask stages are waiting for srcStageMask stages to complete. Or is srcStage = VK_EXTERNAL an exception to the rule? I don't understand that.

Comment: The subpass dependencies simply inform the GPU if and how drawing commands can be executed in parallel, if possible. You only need to set those dependencies without worrying about internal details. For example, if the initial layout is undefined for an attachment, the layout transition could occur when the attachment is actually used (refer to VkAttachmentReference). Otherwise, the GPU may not be allowed to start executing drawing commands from a new subpass. However, these decisions are implementation dependent.