# Explain to me how VkSubpassDependency works

Tags: vulkan

Before my renderPass, there is a swapChain image reading operation, which has its own stages. And we use VkSubpassDependency to wait for VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT to complete the image reading stage (that is, the end of reading the image), and then we start our renderPass, right? srcSubpass = VK_EXTERNAL. I tried to study this question in this tutorial https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation.

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I understand very little

Comment: This user basically keeps asking variations of this same question over and over.  They can't seem to wrap their head around it for whatever reason, so their questions are getting more and more nebulous.

Comment: @Jherico, you're right, this problem still keeps me from exploring vulkan further. For this reason, I ask you to explain this topic to me clearly in order to understand what I do not understand specifically

Comment: @Dimas: Do you know what a subpass is? Do you know how synchronization in general works? Because a subpass dependency is just synchronization between subpasses (or between a subpass and the world outside of the render pass).

Comment: @NicolBolas, I understand what synchronization is. But I don't fully understand what a subpass is

Comment: @Dimas: When I said "how synchronization works", I meant Chapter 7 of the Vulkan specification, not the general concept of synchronizing things.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your previous question: [How does VkSubpassDependency work when srcSubpass = VK\_EXTERNAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075627/how-does-vksubpassdependency-work-when-srcsubpass-vk-external) Please do not duplicate questions. If the answers are not sufficient, please see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @NicolBolas, I get your point, I know about semaphores and fences, but I don't understand SubpassDependency, it's probably because they have stageMasks. Some write that srcStageMask is the stages of the pipeline that must end in order to start the second synchronization area, which must wait on the stages described in dstStageMask. Others write that srcStageMask is the stages whose start will be expected before the srcSubpass subpass begins.

Comment: @Dimas: "*I know about semaphores and fences, but I don't understand SubpassDependency, it's probably because they have stageMasks*" That's the part I don't get. If you understand "semaphores and fences", then what is there to not understand about subpass dependencies? They work the same way, just with a different source/destination scope. They all have stage masks, for example.

Comment: @NicolBolas, what I don't understand about VkSubpassDependency specifically, I wrote in a previous post. This is probably the main contradiction that makes me unable to say that I understand SubpassDependency

Comment: @NicolBolas, answer me please

Comment: @Dimas: You said that what you didn't understand was in a previous post, but you didn't link to that post. So I have no idea what to answer. Furthermore, you already have an answer on this question and on the duplicate, but since you're continuing to ask for an answer, those were not sufficient for you. But again, it's unclear *what* is insufficient about these explanations. So I have no idea how to answer you. Lastly, demanding an answer (even with "please") is perhaps not the most winsome method of getting your questions answered.

Comment: @NicolBolas, "Some write that srcStageMask is the stages of the pipeline that must end in order to start the second synchronization area, which must wait on the stages described in dstStageMask. Others write that srcStageMask is the stages whose start will be expected before the srcSubpass subpass begins." - I do not understand why different srcSubpass parameters change the value of srcStageMask. P.S: I will try not to write a message asking for an answer to my question from now on.

Comment: @Dimas: "*Some write... Others write...*" Those are just different ways of describing what is essentially the same thing. The second scope of a subpass dependency is the stuff in the subpass itself. Therefore, `dstStageMask` always refers to a stage in that subpass. So you could say that the subpass can't start (or at least, can't start that stage) until its dependency is fulfilled. One is just a more precise way of saying the other.

Comment: @NicolBolas, So this means (as written in the tutorial) that the layout transition cannot happen before the COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT stage? If so, can you elaborate on what srcStageMask and dstStageMask do(For example: srcStageMask is needed for something, and dstStageMask for that). I would appreciate it(I just don't have enough specifics, I'm still a beginner, so it's hard to understand anything without illustrative examples).

Comment: @NicolBolas, I thought about it and realized that my question could be simplified: What is srcStageMask in the case srcSubpass = VK_EXTERNAL? Why do operations before renderPass have stage if I have no other Pipeline?

Comment: @Dimas: "*Why do operations before renderPass have stage if I have no other Pipeline?*" What do you mean by "if I have no other Pipeline"? Are you talking about `VkPipeline` objects? Because there are other stages besides those defined by pipeline objects. Furthermore, why would being outside of this render pass prevent you from using pipeline objects? You could be talking about other render passes that executed beforehand or compute operations. External means "external": whatever happened before this render pass instance.

Comment: @NicolBolas, okay, does that mean that getting the image from the swapchain happens at the COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT stage?
P.S: about Pipeline, I assumed that the stages are only there, but apparently they are there without Pipeline

Comment: @NicolBolas, did I get that right?

Comment: @NicolBolas, that is, before my renderPass, there is a swapChain image reading operation, which has its own stages. And we use VkSubpassDependency to wait for VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT to complete the image reading stage (that is, the end of reading the image), and then we start our renderPass, right?
P.S: I think I almost got it

Comment: @NicolBolas, I apologize for the large number of posts, I understood some things after sending my message, and now what I wrote in the last msg is my understanding of how subpassDependency works. Now I would like to know if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I have another question: can the graphicsPipeline steps start before renderPass?

Answer (score 1):

Succinctly, `srcSubpass` in `VkSubpassDependency` refers to the zero-based index  of a subpass that was described in the `pSubpasses` array of `VkRenderPassCreateInfo` when you created the renderpass.

`VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` is a special value that means "Anything that happened prior to this renderpass starting".

> If srcSubpass is equal to VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, **the first synchronization scope includes commands that occur earlier in submission order than the vkCmdBeginRenderPass used to begin the render pass instance**. Otherwise, the first set of commands includes all commands submitted as part of the subpass instance identified by srcSubpass and any load, store or multisample resolve operations on attachments used in srcSubpass. In either case, the first synchronization scope is limited to operations on the pipeline stages determined by the source stage mask specified by srcStageMask.

Sascha Willems has a detailed post describing subpasses and how they work [here](https://www.saschawillems.de/blog/2018/07/19/vulkan-input-attachments-and-sub-passes/) although it doesn't explicitly touch on `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`

In general `VkSubpassDependency` is used to allow the driver to determine what barriers are needed to protect against invalid ordering of rendering commands without requiring the user to explicitly create barriers for each of the attachments.

Comment: The tutorial says it helps to avoid layout transition before getting the image from the Swapchain, but I'm not quite sure how this is related

Comment: I edited my question, I think it makes more sense